# Good practices for versioning Maven multi-module project

Tags: maven

I'm a bit confused about what is the right way to handle modules versioning in a Maven multi-module project. Let me introduce the structure of a fake project to explain my doubts :

```
parent
- libs
  - lib1
  - lib2
- batches
  - batch1
  - batch2
```

Add to this the fact that **batch1** has a dependency on **lib1**, and **batch2** on **lib2**. All these modules are in version 1.0.0. I'm working on a new 1.0.1 version. The only module that has to change in this version is **lib1**. **batch1** does not need to implement these changes until version 1.0.2.

The question is : *what modules should move to version **1.0.1-SNAPSHOT** ?*

My answer would be : **lib1**, **libs** and **parent**. Those are the only modules that actually changed (if we consider that parent modules "contain" their children's code) But some modules would remain children of the obsolete parent 1.0.0, which doesn't sound right.

What would you recommand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no global standard for this, it all depends on your requirement.

So if you have 100 modules then you not release all of them with every release which implies components will be on different versions.

But if you have a small set then you can always upgrade components to new version even if their is no change. In this scenario, you can manage version just by using parent pom version.

EDIT:

As mentioned by OP that he has hunderds of modules, in this case each module should have its own version in its pom. It will not be feasible to keep them at same version all the time. And this is followed in many orgs and projects.

Comment: This example was minimalistic, but my actual project is more like the 100 modules scenario. So what you're saying is that it is acceptable that a release includes several versions of a same library or parent because not all dependencies/inheritances are up to date ?

Comment: See versioning is something which is specific to projects and their use cases. There are only guidelines, so what works for you is acceptable :)